# How to fail a VSTS build task without throwing an exception

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to fail my VSTS build task based on a condition, I'm throwing an error to achieve this from code. This logs an unhanded exception in my build log. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
if (myCollection.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("Build Failed: No data avilable.");
}
```

Comment: What detail result of failed task that you want?

Comment: Can you provide more detailed information? When do you want to fail the build task? During the VSBuild/MSBuild process? Or in a specific build task?

Comment: @Eddie: Its a custom build task of a VSTS extension. I need to fail the build based on some information returned from an external service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  [setResult()](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/vsts-task-lib.md#tasksetResult) method in [vsts-task-lib](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib) to pass or fail the build task.

```
import tl = require('vsts-task-lib/task');

function passorfailtask() {
    tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, 'Build Failed: No data avilable.');
}

passorfailtask()
```